# Find the point of intersection of plan and parabaloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point of intersection of the plane $x+2y+z=10$ and the parabaloid $z=x^2+y^2$ that is closest to the origin. Do this by minimizing the distance squared from the origin: 
$$d^2(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$
with two constrains 
$$g(x,y,z)=x+2y+z=10,\quad  \text{ and }\quad  h(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2-z=0$$

Using Lagrange multipliers solve the system of equations.
Im really lost in this section, but I know that i have to do some derivative to get the right answer

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let us find the points of intersection. Substituting $z=x^2+y^2$ in $x+2y+z=10$, we get $x^2+x+y^2+2y=10$, by completing the square in each variable we get $$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y+1)^2=\frac{45}{4}.$$
Thus, the set of points of intersections are $D:=\{{(x,y)|(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y+1)^2=\frac{45}{4}}\}$. Setting $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y+1)^2-\frac{45}{4}$. Now, using Lagrange multipliers to minimize the function $f=f(x,y,z)$ subject to the side condition $g(x,y,z)=0$. The gradients are $\nabla f\left( {x,y,z} \right) = 2x{\bf{i}} + 2y{\bf{j}} + 2z{\bf{k}}$  and $
\nabla g\left( {x,y,z} \right) = 2\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right){\bf{i}} + 2\left( {y + 1} \right){\bf{j}}$. The Lagrange condition

\begin{align}
\nabla f \times \nabla g &= \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\bf{i}} & {\bf{j}} & {\bf{k}}  \\
   {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} & {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}} & {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}}  \\
   {\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}} & {\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}} & {\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial z}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right|
\\
&= \left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial z}} - \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}}} \right){\bf{i}} - \left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial z}} - \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}} \right){\bf{j}} + \left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial y}} - \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial g}}{{\partial x}}} \right){\bf{k}}
\\
 &= \left\{ {\left( {2y} \right)\left( 0 \right) - \left( {2z} \right)\left( {2\left( {y + 1} \right)} \right)} \right\}{\bf{i}} - \left\{ {\left( {2x} \right)\left( 0 \right) - \left( {2z} \right)\left( {2\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right)} \right\}{\bf{j}}
\\
&+ \left\{ {\left( {2x} \right)\left( {2\left( {y + 1} \right)} \right) - \left( {2y} \right)\left( {2\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right)} \right\}{\bf{k}}
\\
 &= 4z\left( {y + 1} \right){\bf{i}} - 4z\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right){\bf{j}} + \left( {4x\left( {y + 1} \right) - 4y\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right){\bf{k}}
\\
&={\bf{0}}
\end{align}
which gives that $$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 4z\left( {y + 1} \right) = 0 \\ 
  - 4z\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right) = 0 \\ 
 4x\left( {y + 1} \right) - 4y\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right) = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$ simplifying the equations, $$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 zy + z = 0 \\ 
 z - 2zx = 0 \\ 
 2x + y = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. 
$$ One can observe that these equations are linearly '*dependent*' therefore let $x=t$ , ($t$ is real) be a dummy variable so that $y=-2t$ and $z=0$. Thus, the solution is 
$$
\left\{ {\left( {x,y,z} \right)|x = t,y =  - 2y,z = 0,t \in {\bf{R}}} \right\}.$$ However, using the side condition the solution reduces to $$
\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2  + \left( {y + 1} \right)^2  = \left( {t - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2  + \left( { - 2t + 1} \right)^2  = \frac{{45}}{4}
,$$ we find $t=-1,2$ thus our points are 
$$
\left\{ {\left( {-1,2,0} \right),\left( {2,-4,0} \right)} \right\}.$$ 
Finally, we have $f\left( { - 1,2,0} \right) = 1 + 4 + 0 = 5$ and $f\left( {2,4,0} \right) = 4 + 16 + 0 = 20$, so that the minimum is $d^2=5$ occurred at $\left( {-1,2,0} \right)$.